# Allow external users to edit report

Tags: powerbi

I have enabled the [Share content with external users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-portal#export-and-sharing-settings) feature in the Power BI admin portal and also used the [Allow external guest users to edit and manage content in the organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-portal#allow-external-guest-users-to-edit-and-manage-content-in-the-organization) feature.

I'm able to share a report with external users.

However, the can't edit the report.

Why, and how can I solve this?

Comment: Are they invited to the workspace?

Comment: Actually, no because in this same workspace I have other reports I don't want to share with this user.

Comment: I do not know if what you want is possible. You could try with internal user. If that user cannot edit either, it might be a workspace access issue